# Node.js websocket delay close event

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, websocket

Are they any options for changing node.js 'ws' to be more sensitive for closing sockets. 
At the moment it takes too long for me until the event is risen.

Even in cases when my client closes the socket the event is risen many seconds later.

Comment: Is it just a network latency issue?  That's obviously going to be a lower bound on how quickly the event can be triggered.

Comment: No this occures within one computer. So latency is unrealistically low.